# Linked/ArrayList not functioning as expected

Tags: java, android

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

    event.setName(parser.getValue(e, NODE_NAME));
    event.setDate(parser.getValue(e, NODE_DATE));
    event.setLocation(parser.getValue(e, NODE_LOC));

    Log.d("Thisworks!:", event.getName());
    eventsList.addLast(event);
}

for (Event curevent : eventsList) {
    Log.d("ThisDoesnt!?:", curevent.getName());
}
```

Output should be:

```
name1
name1
name1
name2
name2
name3
name3
```

Thisworks! outputs different values every time, as expected.

But when i loop through the list and output, it only outputs:

```
name3 
name3 
name3 
name3 
name3 
name3 
name3
```

Am i missing something completely obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

You should be adding a new `Event` to the `eventsList` each time through the loop, not setting the values of the same `event`.

`eventsList.addLast(event)` does *not* make a copy, it just adds a reference to `event` to the list.  So there is only ever one `event` object, which you keep overwriting.

Comment: Thanks, i had the new Event just above the loop :/

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to create a new Event object in your loop. What's happening is that the **same** Event object keeps getting updated. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
    Event event = new Event(); // You're missing this.

    event.setName(parser.getValue(e, NODE_NAME));
    event.setDate(parser.getValue(e, NODE_DATE));
    event.setLocation(parser.getValue(e, NODE_LOC));              

    Log.d("Thisworks!:", event.getName());            
    eventsList.addLast(event);
}
```

Comment: I tried that but got error: 
    Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable.

nodeList is of type NodeList